# Handling Screen Readers ARIA

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

I've been reading about using ARIA to get screen readers to read labels that otherwise wouldn't be there. However, I'm having a hard time getting a dropdown menu (from Foundation 6) to be read. Consider this piece of code:

```
<li role="menuitem">
    <label id="label1" class="sr-only">Testing click label</label>
    <a class="submenu-link" href="/" tabindex="1">
        <span class="has-tip right" data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" title="Foundation tooltip">
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
            <span class="text" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="label1">Click here</span>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
```

There are two things I'm baffled about:

1. Why isn't the `<a>` tag being read by the screen reader like all others that aren't in a menu dropdown?
2. Why isn't the `aria-labelledby` being read?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's the "aria-hidden" on the span. As far as the screenreader can tell, that link has nothing in it.

Also:

- `label` might seem like a logical thing here, but it's actually only intended for use with inputs.
- Putting `aria-hidden` and `aria-labelledby` on the same element doesn't really make sense.
- Avoid `tabindex=1`; use `0` if you need it to be clickable/focusable by the user, or `-1` if you just need to be able to focus it via javascript.
- There's a lot going on in your code sample; can you explain or show what it is you're trying to achieve? Why is there a dropdown item with a label, with a tooltip with an icon in it? How is this menu item supposed to look and function? What do each of these labels actually represent?

Adding labels where appropriate is definitely good to think about, but wherever possible, let normal markup do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I forgot to comment on this. I found out that things were actually working, but rather hearing the screen reader on hover, the reader was actually speaking the labels when pressing Tab. So I didn't need the ```label``` nor ```aria-labelledby```. That was out of desperation.

On another note, you're right, there's a lot going on with my code which is a result of not handling accessibility sooner. Also, I'm using Foundation. This is a menu item from their Dropdown Menu section. Thanks for the suggestions and I will keep them in mind on future projects.